# Routing Application in Windows

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, geoserver, routing, windows

I am making an routing web application similar to Google Maps `Get Direction` feature. But because of the limited control and data on Google Maps, I decided to use OpenStreetMap instead. This also made me install PostGIS-PostgreSQl database, added routing functionality using `pgRouting` and now, I'm planning to use a GeoServer. All of these are done in Ubuntu Linux 9.04. My problem is I have difficulty using Linux and I'm more comfortable with Windows. As much as possible, I want to use Windows, but some of the things that I need are tested only in Linux (like osm2pgrouting, which I need to import OSM data to my database).

Is there a way I can implement the project using Windows, to avoid using Linux?

Comment: I think you can install all the applications you listed on Windows. Have you seen this link: http://postgis.net/windows_downloads/ ? It mentions providing the osm2pgrouting as a commandline utility also.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Gosmore#Windows

Though you might find a more suitable application here:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers

All are opensource so you can customise for your needs.